# Github action Artifact not uploaded WinUI3 app

Tags: github-actions, winui-3, msix

I am trying WinUI3 and Github action for the first time using this link :

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/ci-for-winui3?pivots=winui3-packaged-csharp
```

After successful workflowrun, its not uploading the Msix file:

[image]

I am confused at the following as in what should be my approach :

1. bin folder does not exist in the repository, so should I create one ?
2. The solution on my system (the solution folder) has a bin folder, should I include that in the repository ?

Also I wanted to know regarding WinUI3 desktop app, how can I send the installation (set up file) to another user ?

If I am running on my system the (MSIX) file it works created using Package & publish, because trust certificate is local, but when I send it to someone it says not signed. What is the approach in WiNUI3 for set up & installation (like WPF had) ?

[image]

**Question Update:**

Workflow file (yml)

```
    # This workflow will build and publish a WinUI 3 unpackaged desktop application
# built on .NET.

name: WinUI 3 unpackaged app

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:

  build:

    strategy:
      matrix:
        configuration: [Release]
        platform: [x64, x86]

    runs-on: windows-latest  # For a list of available runner types, refer to
                             # https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idruns-on

    env:
      Solution_Name: TestMatchReplay.sln                         # Replace with your solution name, i.e. App1.sln.

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0

    # Install the .NET Core workload
    - name: Install .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x

    # Add  MSBuild to the PATH: https://github.com/microsoft/setup-msbuild
    - name: Setup MSBuild.exe
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

    # Restore the application to populate the obj folder with RuntimeIdentifiers
    - name: Restore the application
      run: msbuild $env:Solution_Name /t:Restore /p:Configuration=$env:Configuration
      env:
        Configuration: ${{ matrix.configuration }}

    # Create the app by building and publishing the project
    - name: Create the app
      run: msbuild $env:Solution_Name /t:Publish /p:Configuration=$env:Configuration /p:Platform=$env:Platform
      env:
        Configuration: ${{ matrix.configuration }}
        Platform: ${{ matrix.platform }}

    # Upload the app
    - name: Upload app
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: Upload app
        path: ${{ env.Solution_Name }}\\bin
```

Comment: Please add your relevant workflow in your question. Apparently, the executable path is not correct so you need to verify the path where your binaries are located; maybe, by running `dir` or `ls` command and using that in the upload step. And, for the singing part, you need to sign your app in your workflow to distribute it properly.

Comment: For code signing, you could directly use the `signtool` or use these actions (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/signtool-code-sign, https://github.com/marketplace/actions/code-sign-a-file-with-pfx-certificate, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your response Azeem. My workflow is same as mentioned in the Microsoft link above. I have pasted the code above. Also where should I run dir/ls in github ? as run command in yml file ? My apologies for asking basic question as i am new to github action

Comment: Also if you can help me underestand w.r.t signTool, as they ask to purchase a certificate first, is it also a requirement during development ? is it possible to sign the app without purchasing atleast till development ?

Comment: You need to verify after the build step so add `dir` or `ls` accordingly. How do you sign the binaries locally?

Comment: Using the "create" certificate in Package & Publish and clicking on Trust. So when launched it shows verified on my machine,

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely lies within the path you are trying to access. The error log indicates that it is trying to upload the file `TestMatchReplay.sln\\bin`, however if you build the app, the output will land inside the bin folder of the C# project, not a folder named after the solution, I think this is an issue with the documentation of the CI. If you change the last step to the following it should probably work:

```yaml
    - name: Upload app
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: Upload app
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}\\bin
```

Regarding sending the file to another user, you will either need to sign your app with a valid NOT SELF-SIGNED certificate or send the certificate you created to the user so they can install the certificate on their machine. Note that the latter can be a huge security risk for any users doing this if at some point your key leaks. You can find more information on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool).